# eXosip: login always fails on first try

Tags: c++, authentication, sip, exosip

I am developing a SIP-Application using `eXosip`. When I try to login to the server the first attempt always fails.

```
eXosip_lock(ctx);
eXosip_add_authentication_info(ctx, username, login, passwd, NULL, domain);

osip_message_t *reg;
int rid = eXosip_register_build_initial_register(ctx, account, server, NULL, 3600, &reg);

// Not sure what they do, but they seem to be necessary
osip_message_set_supported (reg, "100rel");
osip_message_set_supported (reg, "path");

eXosip_register_send_register(ctx, rid, reg);
eXosip_unlock(ctx);
```

(I've removed error checking to make it more readable.) The above code results in an EXOSIP_REGISTER_FAILED event. Reacting to this event by executing the following code results in a successful registration.

```
eXosip_lock(ctx);

osip_message_t *reg;
eXosip_register_build_register(ctx, rid, 3600, &reg);
eXosip_register_send_register(ctx, rid, reg);

eXosip_unlock(ctx);
```

I tried different accounts at different providers and it's always the same.
Granted, it works, but it makes the program flow confusing and error handling harder (e.g. for erroneous login credentials), which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Now I don't know if this behavior is to be expected (I couldn't find anything about it), but... can anybody help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was a bit stupid. For anyone who wonders or encounters the same, most servers will reply to the initial register with a 401 (unauthorized) or 407 (proxy authentication required). Knowing this I was able to successfully register using the following code:

```
eXosip_automatic_action(ctx);

if (evt->type == EXOSIP_REGISTER_FAILED)
{
   if (evt->response != NULL &&
          (evt->response->status_code == 401 || evt->response->status_code == 407))
   {
       eXosip_default_action(ctx, evt);
   }
   else
       // login really failed
}
```

`eXosip_automatic_action` will handle 401, 407, 422, 3xx and reregister before the registration expires. `eXosip_default_action` will handle some more things regarding 401/407. Quite handy!

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty old question, but I would like to offer a precise answer:

About the question itself:

**eXosip_automatic_action(ctx);** will handle every automatic actions but there are only 2 use-cases that cannot be handled with it and EXOSIP_REGISTRATION_FAILURE is not part of them.

Here is the correct way to activate all automatic actions required by an eXosip based application:

```
int status_code = 0;
if (evt->response != NULL)
  status_code = evt->response->status_code;

eXosip_automatic_action(ctx);

if (evt->type == EXOSIP_CALL_MESSAGE_REQUESTFAILURE && evt->did < 0) {
  /* evt->did<0 means dialog is over, but authentication is required (BYE was rejected) */
  if (status_code == 407 || status_code == 401)
    eXosip_default_action (evt);
}

if (evt->type == EXOSIP_MESSAGE_REQUESTFAILURE && evt->request != NULL) {
  /* authentication is required for a message without context in exosip (MESSAGE, OPTIONS...) */
  if (!MSG_IS_PUBLISH (evt->request) && (status_code == 407 || status_code == 401))
    eXosip_default_action (evt);
}
```

As indicated in the code comments, the above code will also authenticate sip messages outside dialog (MESSAGE, OPTIONS, etc...) and sip messages within a terminated dialog (mostly BYE)